# CSS - URL Import rewrites own styles

Tags: css

In my vue project I'm using bootstrap (5.0) and a font from google fonts.

I noticed, that even though the import is written first in the screen.css file and the own style second that the import rewrites the own styles. when inspecting the h1 element the own style gets cancelled out and the `font-weight: 500` comes from the bootstrap css file.

is there any way to ensure a sequential reading of the screen.css file?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;400;600;800&display=swap');
@import url('./bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css');

:root{
  --text-primary: rgb(17, 24, 39);
  --sans-serif: 'Inter', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
}

body{
  font-family: var(--sans-serif);
  color: var(--text-primary);
}

h1, h2, h3{
  font-family: var(--sans-serif);
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`.h1`, `.h2` and `.h3` (class selectors) have higher specificity than `h1`, `h2` and `h3` (element selectors) respectively and if the same specificity is there, the rule that came later will override the styles of the rule that came earlier.

**Examples**

```css
div, p {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* The rule with `border: 0.1em solid red;` came later than the rule with `border 0.1em solid black` */

div {
    border: 0.1em solid black;
}

div {
   border: 0.1em solid red;
}

/* `.example` selector has higher specificity than `p` selector */

.example {
    background: #043240;
    color: white;
}

p {
    background: #202020;
}

/* Use `!important` in the declaration before the semicolon to force a declaration

this will be applied to the declaration with same specificity that came later or a selector with higher specify

Trying removing this from one of the two rules below

Avoid using this */

#important {
    background: pink !important;
}

.important {
    background: skyblue !important;
}
```

```html
<div>Example 1</div>

<p class="example">Example 2</p>

<p id="important" class="important">Example 3</p>
```

**Links**

[Specificity on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

[!important on MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception)

*More links*

[`:where` video by Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvH35ZFPbc4)

[`@layer` video by Kevin Powell](https://youtu.be/Pr1PezCc4FU)

Answer (score 1):

Like previous answers, this is all a priority issue, if you can, define a new CSS file with more specific rule to match your `h1` tag. For example you can surrond every h1 tag with a div with a new class.

```
<div class='title'>
  <h1>My title</h1>
</div>

<style>
.class h1
{
  font-weight : 500;
}
</style>
```

But if you want to bypass selector priority you can use `!important` keyword in a new CSS file.

Note that this is bad practice and you should always define a clean element architecture.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors (such as `.h1`) have higher weight/priority than tag selectors (such as `h1`).

If you give your rules the same or higher weight the rules will be read sequentially.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity